# can't change attr with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themes, fullscreen, attr

Why doesn't this code work:

```
$("#page1").live('pageinit', function() {
    if (localStorage.fullscreen == "true") {
        $("#page1").attr("data-fullscreen", "true"); // doesn't work
        alert("should be fullscreen now"); // this works
    }
    if (localStorage.theme) {
        $("header").attr("data-theme", localStorage.theme); // this doesn't work
        alert("should be theme " + localStorage.theme); // this works
    }
 });
```

[According to the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/attr/index.html), it should work.  I've also tried

```
$("header").data("theme", localStorage.theme);
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?  The attributes are likely getting set, but that won't change anything in your page unless you run some other code or have CSS that looks at those attributes.

Comment: have you tried this in a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery data api:

```
 $("#page1").data("fullscreen", "true");
 $("header").data("theme", localStorage.theme);
```

refer to: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and for some reason the fullscreen worked but the theme didn't. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Do your headers have the attribute "data-role='page'"? _The data-theme attribute can be applied to the header and footer containers to apply any of the lettered theme color swatches. While the data-theme attribute could be added to the content container, we recommend adding it instead to div or container that has been assigned the data-role="page" attribute to ensure that the background color is applied to the full page._ [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/pages/pages-themes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another event, because on `pageinit` the page already got enhanced and is ignoring your additional attributes.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Try using `pagecreate` or `pagebeforecreate` instead.

This should work:

```
$("#page1").live('pagecreate', function() {
    if (localStorage.fullscreen == "true") {
        $("#page1").attr("data-fullscreen", "true"); // doesn't work
        alert("should be fullscreen now"); // this works
    }
    if (localStorage.theme) {
        $("header").attr("data-theme", localStorage.theme); // this doesn't work
        alert("should be theme " + localStorage.theme); // this works
    }
});
```